# Warhammer Fantasy Tournaments Statistics

Tags: statistics, tournament, warhammer-fantasy

I'm looking for raw tournaments result database/statistics, divided per format, date and including army distribution

something like this : [tabletoptournaments.net](http://www.tabletoptournaments.net/t3_armies.php?gid=1&cid=0&latest=1)

but where I cand filter by date and format, and with complete data (here, there are 165 victories on 3967 armies.. a lot of draws!)

does it exist?

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

[Rankings HQ](http://www.rankingshq.com/default.aspx) is probably the closest you can get to what you are looking for.  There are a couple of disclaimers to add though.

- The pool of ranked games is going to be pretty small.
- The ranking is elective, so there's going to be lots of missing data.
- It won't track information about particular tournament formats, just the results.

Torrent of Fire is a paid service that comes closer to what you want, but it's only for 40K.  I think they where planning on branching out to Fantasy. With Fantasy's declining popularity and GW's current financial implosions, I don't know if we'll see that happen any time soon.